# Cannot access ubuntu server from other machines other than the machine which is hosting the virtual machine which is my ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I created a ubuntu server on vmware. I am using it as a file server. I can access it if I am connecting through the machine which hosts the virtual machine. I am not able to do it from other machines which are on the same network. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try checking the firewall rules and check the settings of the vmware machine and what types of network connection does it shows...

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure in the setting of the virtual machine that it is in `Bridged Adaptor` type connectivity.
2. Give a static ip to the virtual machine using

   `sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0`

the above is an example. You got what I mean.

3.Third, Try pinging the virtual machine with the base machine running the vbox to make sure they are connected.

```
 ping ipaddress-basemachine
```

4 . Now if everything is working fine from there then connect with this virtual machine with other base machine using `Remote Desktop Viewer` or any other similar application.

Specify, the ip-address of the vbox and username, password. It will be able to connect with it now.

5 . If it still is not able to then try to check the firewall rules on both the virtual box machine and the base machine running the vbox using the command

```
iptables -L
```